# displaying items in array ordered by id inside string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I want to display items in an array separately, ordered by groups.

The items are stored in a string like this:

```
$itemsString = "1:asd, 1:wer, 2:dfg, 3:gfg, 3:sdfss"; //and so forth
```

Then I display them like this:

```
$itemsArray = explode(", ", $itemsString);
foreach($itemsArray as $item){
 echo substr($item,2); //substr to get rid of the group id
}
```

EDIT: **solution**

```
if(strpos($item, "1:")!==false){
echo substr($item,2);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain which operation you intend to do with the data when the group id is '1:'?

Comment: I just want to display it

Comment: What's wrong with using the same `echo` line from your first block of code?

Comment: you're right.. I've tried it but I made a mistake somehow and then thought it couldn't be done.. idk why.. it's working fine now.. well thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform another explode on your initial array on the colon, seperate the number and the value, then feed them into a array using the number as the key, eg:

```
$itemsString = "1:asd, 1:wer, 2:dfg, 3:gfg, 3:sdfss"; //and so forth

$sorted_array = [];
$itemsArray = explode(", ", $itemsString);
foreach($itemsArray as $item) {
    $subItemsArray = explode(":", $item);
    $sorted_array[$subItemsArray[0]][] = $subItemsArray[1];
}

print_r($sorted_array);
```

Which would mean `$sorted_array` would be pre-sorted for you (or easily sortable with [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd
            [1] => wer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dfg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => gfg
            [1] => sdfss
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can display them like this

```
$itemsArray = explode(", ", $itemsString);
foreach($itemsArray as $item){
  if(strpos($item, "1:") || strpos($item, "1:") ===0 ){
    echo substr($item,2)
    ;}
}
```